# JavaFX - Using Other Classes As Nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and am curious about whether or not it is possible to add objects of your own classes as Nodes to a scene in the main start function? For example, I would like to create a root Node in my start function and then add a Button to it. Instead of creating the Button in the same start function, is it possible to instantiate an Object, which creates its own button in its constructor, and then add that to the root Node? Here's what I mean. I have two classes that I'm working with. Main and Bar. Here is my main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();

    Bar open = new Bar();

    root.getChildren().add(open);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024,768, Color.BLACK);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

And Here Is My Bar Class:

```
public class Bar extends BorderPane {

public Bar()
{
    Button btn = new Button("hey"); 
}
```

}

When I launch the application, a 1024 X 768 black box open up but there is no Button on it. Why? When I create my Bar object (open), its default constructor creates a Button. That Bar object is then added as one of the children to my root object in main. If my bar object is now one of the root object's children, and the root object is used in the Scene, shouldn't the button from the Bar object's constructor show up when I launch the app?

On a larger scale, is this typically done in Javafx? Having everything in a separate class and keeping the main start function as clean as possible Or is it ok to instantiate various objects in that function? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the button as a child to the `Bar` (which is actually a `BorderPane`):

```
public class Bar extends BorderPane {
    public Bar()
    {
        Button btn = new Button("hey");
        setCenter(btn);
    }
}
```

Generally there are two main approaches when building up larger UIs:

**(1) Every UI-Komponent is a subclass of a `Node` type** (e.g. `BorderPane` as in your case) and builds up the user interface in its constructor. The UI-Komponent is part of the JavaFX scene graph.

- Advantage: Simple usage - just instantiate your class and put it into the scene graph as any child node.
- Disadvantage: All UI is created in the constructor. Controller code is part of the UI.

**(2) Every UI-Komponent is represented by a class that is *not* a subclass of a `Node` type.** Instead, a method like `createUI(Pane parent)` creates the UI and puts it into the scene graph. This method must be called explicitely.

Example:

```
public class Bar {
    public void createUI(Pane parent) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Button btn = new Button("hey");
        pane.setCenter(btn);

        parent.getChildren().add(pane);
    }
}
```

In the `start(Stage)` method of the main application:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.createUI(root);
```

Of course, a complex UI-component might internally use other UI-components and call their `createUI(...)` method from its own `createUI(...)` method.

- Advantage: Separation of UI and controller. Explicit method for building the UI, so the component might be instantiated and configured *before* the UI is built up.
- Disadvantage: More complex to use.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Is that a general rule then? If you want to add objects of different classes as Nodes in your main start function, the objects contained in those classes must first be added as children of the class?

Comment: It just behaves the same way as anything else. If you want a `Button` to appear in the scene graph, you add it to the child list of some parent node (and that node is added as the child of some other parent node, etc, all the way up to the root of the `Scene`). It doesn't matter if the `Parent` node is from the standard JavaFX library or one of your own classes.

Comment: That's huge! Thanks a lot for the responses, I appreciate it.