# JavaFX - Splitting GUI into separate classes while using tabs

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a program with a tabbed GUI where each tab's contents are their own class.  I essentially want to do what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313240/javafx-using-other-classes-as-nodes), but with tabs.  Mere is the Manager class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Manager extends Application {

    private TabPane tabPane;
    private Tab dcTab;

    public Manager() {

        dcTab = new Tab();

        tabPane = new TabPane();

        DistributionCenter dcMenu = new DistributionCenter();

        dcTab.setText("Distribution Center");
        dcTab.setContent(dcMenu);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(dcTab);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Group root = new Group();

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 600, 500);

        DistributionCenter dcMenu = new DistributionCenter();
        root.getChildren().add(dcMenu);
        dcTab.setContent(dcMenu);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("909th Wing");

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here is my DistributionCenter class:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class DistributionCenter extends Pane {

    private Button testBt1;

    public DistributionCenter() {

        Pane dcMenu = new Pane();

        testBt1 = new Button("Button");
        dcMenu.getChildren().addAll(testBt1);

        testBt1.setLayoutX(30);
        testBt1.setLayoutY(100);

    }
}
```

Note that the contents of DistributionCenter are just a test at this point.

Comment: Okay, so that's what you want to do; what is your question? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Zephyr The problem I'm having is that there is a tab, but no contents from DistributionCenter.  I've tried both approaches from the answer provided to the linked question, and I think the problem is arising from my use of the tab.

Comment: @Zephyr I'm not sure what you mean by "`dcTab` is not a 'Tab'".  What does 'dcTab = new Tab()' do then?

Comment: Yikes. I'm not sure what I was reading... but why are you creating a new `DistributionCenter` and setting the tab contents twice?

Comment: @Zephyr That was a result of my extensive experimenting trying to get the program to work.  I forgot to remove the excess code when I moved it (I don't remember which code is the original and which is the new).

Answer (score 1):

You are never adding your `Button` to the actual `DistributionCenter` pane. Instead, you are creating a new `Pane` within that class and adding the button to it.

Remember, `DistributionCenter` **is** a `Pane` so it has its own children. You do not need to create a new `Pane` within it.

Update your `DistributionCenter` class to just configure itself:

```
public DistributionCenter() {

    testBt1 = new Button("Button");
    getChildren().addAll(testBt1);

}
```

---

That will solve your problem, but you should never extend a class unless you need to implement different **behavior**. If you are just configuring a `Node` like this, you should just create an instance of a `Pane` and configure it properly.